# No Method error in UsersController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nomethoderror

I began coding in Rails several weeks ago, and I can't figure out why I have this error. I'm using Devise for log-ins and Formtastic for forms. The app was working correctly until I added the Acts_like_tags_on and reset the database.

The error message:
    NoMethodError in UsersController#show

```
undefined method `username' for nil:NilClass

app/controllers/users_controller.rb:19:in `show'
Request

Parameters:
{"id"=>"sign_in"}
```

This is what I have in the Users Controller:

```
def show
 @user = User.find_by_username(params[:id])
 @title = @user.username

 respond_to do |format|
   format.html # show.html.erb
   format.json { render json: @user }
 end
end
```

Any input would be helpful. Thanks!

After editing @user = User.find_by_username(params[:id]) to:
@user = User.find_by_user(params[:id])

The error becomes:
    undefined method `find_by_user' for #

The username column does exist in the User table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually a routing problem

The problem is that devise expects you to have a route that will turn:

"/users/sign_in" into sessions#new

but your routes file is missing that route, and so the dispatcher is matching against the:

"users/:id" route which then goes to:
users#show with :id => 'sign_in'

(and hence throws an error when it tries to find a user with the id of "sign_in")

You need to read the README doc for devise (google if you don't have it locally) - especially the part that describes how to add the standard set of routes to config/routes.rb Then do whatever it says. :)

Should be right after that.

Comment: That solved it, Taryn. Thank you! I had been reading things from the README, but overlooked the routing. After I added the following line in my routes, the sign_up (etc.) is now at account/sign_up, and is no longer confusing 'sign_up' as a user: 

  devise_for :users, :path => "account", :path_names => { :sign_in => 'login', :sign_out => 'logout', :password => 'secret', :confirmation => 'verification', :unlock => 'unblock', :registration => 'register', :sign_up => 'sign_up' }

Comment: Yay. I got caught by this one myself... good to see my own experience at it can help somebody else :)

Answer (score 2):

```
@user = User.find_by_username(params[:id])
```

That line above may be returning nil. If you do User.find_by_username("Superman-is-awesome") and that username does not exist in your database, it's going to return nil.

Then it is trying to do:

```
@title = @user.username
```

Which is essentially:

```
@title = nil.username
```

Which of course won't work. So could be something wrong with the parameter you are passing in.

Also, make sure your User table have a column called 'username'? Make sure you've run:

```
rake db:migrate
```

As well.

Comment: That makes sense. I changed the line to:
@user = User.find_by_user(params[:id])

Now the error is:
undefined method `find_by_user' for #<Class:0x0000000464f128>

Comment: Instead of find_by_user, it would just be find(params[:id]) All you need to do to find a User is pass the id.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I put: @user = User.find(params[:id]) and now I'm getting this: ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in UsersController#show
  
Couldn't find User with ID=sign_up

Comment: So it sounds like you're trying to access yoursite.com/users/sign_up, but it is looking for a user with the id of sign_up. Are you using Devise? If so, install it with 'rails g devise:install' then do 'rails g devise User'. You may need to delete your previous 'create_user' migration in db/migrations. And add your custom fields (if any) to the new user table via new migrations. Make sure in your routes file you have 'devise_for :users' and 'resources :users' Then you should be good to go. Check out the Railscasts by Ryan Bates. Head to http://railscasts.com and search 'Devise'. There are two.

Comment: Yes, I'm using Devise. It was working really well until I installed Acts_like_tags_on, so I'm wondering if that caused the issue (I did reset the db). Thanks again for your input!

Comment: Hmm... I am using acts_as_taggable_on. I got it from here: https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on

The instructions were pretty good, and I didn't have any issues.

Comment: Wait, you're right. That's the gem I installed (I've been staring at the screen for a couple hours trying to figure this out). :)

Comment: Well, I'm really glad I was able to help you. I've really enjoyed working with you. Just make sure to mark the correct answer on all of your questions. Have a great day!

Comment: I went through the Devise setup again (thanks for the video tip), and added username to User (I reset the db and removed migrate files). I still have the same error as before. :(

Comment: I think what's happening is that it's taking the users/sign_up and looking for a user with the ID of "sign_up", instead of routing me to the sign_up page (rake routes shows that the path exists).

Comment: So after commenting out "resources :users", the sign_up page became accessible. But after signing up, I saw this on my server: "SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 0 LIMIT 1 
Completed 404 Not Found in 171ms

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find User with ID=users):
  app/controllers/users_controller.rb:17:in `show'"

Comment: Make sure you have BOTH: 'devise_for :users' AND 'resources :users'. The devise_for :users allows the /users/sign_in and /users/sign_out to work. Then the resources :users allows things like /users/1 to work, or /users/1/edit, etc

Answer (score 1):

If you configured the routes correctly, you should have devise routes BEFORE user resource, like this:

```
devise_for :users
resources :users, except: "create"
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that the user_id was being given the value of 'users'. After commenting the following line out in my routes.rb, the id was no longer given that value.

```
match '/:id' => 'users#show', :as => :user
```

I also needed the users_controllers #show to have the following line, since my user path uses the username. removing '_by_username' caused an error on pages that called for the username:

```
@user = User.find_by_username(params[:id])
```